# Can't send mails through PHP, even I set MX records

Tags: php, email, digital-ocean, mx-record, pointers

I am using PHP's mail() function, but I am unable to send mails to the majority of servers.
It send mails to the GMAIL without problems...Probably the rest of servers simply deny my mails...I set the MX records of the mail servers that I need...And I changed my PTR record to mail.example.com......however stil cant send mails..How can I solve this problem?

In addition, messages' sender is displayed as "www-data@localhost"

(I am using Digital Ocean, Ubuntu 12.04)

Errors that I am getting in log file:

> My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry localhost sendmail[11620]: unable to qualify my own domain name (localhost) -- using short name(errors that I get in mail.err); and in log file it shows some errors regarding verification, Do I need to install smt regarding STARTTLS=client

Comment: php's mail() is good for quick/dirty/simple emails. but they have a HIGH probability of getting trashed as spam. don't use it. use a proper mail library, like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: Try to use from address.

Comment: Check if you have set up properly your mail server. Using postfix? And @MarcB is right. Better to use mail libraries. I advice swiftmailer.

Comment: Sorry to be frank, but based on your question, you should not be trying to set up a mail server.  Hire a consultant or use a commercial email service.

Answer (score 0):

when using the mail() function  ypou neet to set the SENDER as well as teh from/to etc.

i.e.

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f ".$webmaster);
```

The important thing is that `"-f ".$webmaster` that allows you to override the default of 'www-data@localhost' as the BOUNCE address (Envelope sender)  for failed mail..

Most mailers will reject e-mail with an invalid bounce address.

Many hosted servers will not let you set the -f value tho...it sets the 'real sender' and of course its a classic way to send spam..

Try  with the -f and if it fails change your hosting company.
Or get yourself a virtual private server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and one thing you can do is: open a ticket with digital ocean support. By default, new accounts have a block to send e-mails (to avoid spammers). They resolved quickly and greatly improved.

Another thing is: check your mail reputation. You can find some websites that can help with this, like mail-tester.com - This site provides a report with potencial issues to fix the problem.